# Is this true ? $a^3c \pmod{ab} = c \pmod{b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is this true $a^3c \pmod{ab} = c \pmod{b}$ ?

I noticed this today and it seems to be true as all the examples I have tried worked... Is there an easy way to make sense of why this true ? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample $a=2, \ b=5, \ c=3$ ?

Comment: Wow! nice example xD thanks that puts end to my trails.. :)

Comment: Hey can I say $a^3c \pmod{ab} = a^3c \pmod{b}$ ?? @qwr

Comment: yes, because if $a \equiv c \mod pq$ then $a-c = kpq$ and then if $k' = kp$ then $a-c = k'q$ and $a \equiv c \mod q$ (In this case the $a$ and $c$ values are different than the ones you use, meaning this works for any value let alone just $a^3c$)